# Rails sending outdated file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So i have a rails app that outputs some files in my `folhas_controller.rb` :

```
  def show
    @folha = Folha.find(params[:id])
    @servicos = @folha.servicos
    nome = "#{@folha.nome_do_mes}-#{@folha.ano}-#{DateTime.now.to_i}"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.csv { send_data @folha.to_csv, filename: "#{nome}.csv" }
      format.xlsx do
        xlsx_package = @folha.to_xls
        begin
          temp = Tempfile.new("folha.xlsx")
          xlsx_package.serialize temp.path
          xlsx_package.use_shared_strings
          send_file temp.path, filename: "#{nome}.xlsx", type: "application/xlsx"
        ensure
        temp.close
        temp.unlink
        end
      end
      format.pdf do
        pdf = @folha.to_pdf(view_context)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "#{nome}.pdf", type: "application/pdf"#, disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end
```

Things was just fine in development.
Then i deployed to heroku and my `<%= link_to image_tag('xls_small.png'), folha_path(folha, format: 'xlsx'), class: 'item' %>` keep sending me a file generated in past, including the old filename. How to remove these oldfiles and force Rails to generate a new one?

Comment: Why do you believe it is Rails and not an old copy in cache on the server?

Comment: The filename carriers the old time finger print, it responds with the send_file but does not executte nothing else...
If the file is an old copy in cache, how can i remove and prevent this behavior?

Comment: check if such a file is in your public folder and remove it